# How @DeclareRoles define users within a particular role?

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6

I have been searching this for quite some times but out of luck. When I use `@DeclareRoles("javaee6user")`, how should I declare which user I should tied to this role? This for example the following code was using this `@DeclareRoles`:

```
@DeclareRoles("javaee6user")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

BTW, as my understanding is this annotation is Glassfish specification, can I use it in other enterprise server like WebSphere and JBoss?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the environment you deploy into. The reason is simple - the application developer can't know (and shouldn't need to) how and where the security information is stored in the environment into which the application will be deployed. So this mapping (users or groups to application roles) is intended and should be done at deployment into a specific environment.

For example, on GlassFish, here's how you do it - [official Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html#bnbxv).

The `@DeclareRoles` is part of the Java EE specification (5 and up I believe), therefore you can use it on any compliant server.